# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n/2} +n +1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I don't know how to solve this question: Solve the recurrence relation $a_{n}=a_{n/2}+n+1$ with $a_1=1$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Wouldn't it be $a_{n+1}=$ ?

Comment: @Bernard It's $a_n=a_{n/2}+...$, based on the body of the question.

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem alone? What were your attempts? For example, did you try to calculate some of the values and try to find a pattern?

Comment: @ Botond yeah please help me!

Comment: Bu if $n=3$, what happens?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your work? People are more willing to help if you write down your own thoughts and not just tell them that "here is my homework, solve it for me!".

Comment: @ Botond  i have solve similar problems but when i found this question i cant attempt this one

Comment: How can you compute $a_{\frac{7}{2}}$ for example?

Comment: @ Botond  its not my homework or else i am just preparing for my exam i have solve other recurence releation question but for this one i have not any idea !please anybody who can help me !!

Comment: @Gone Lastvirus: $n$ has to be even?

Comment: I believe one would usually use Master's theorem on a recursion like this. Have you tried that?

Comment: i don't know much about it but i think we can solve this by Divide and Conquer algorithms. i am not sure i google it and i found some similar problem with half indices

Comment: @Arthur No i never heard about such theorem

Comment: Apparently I mean [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). Shows how much I know.

Comment: You might be interested in the [OEIS sequence A083706](https://oeis.org/A083706). $a(2^n) = A083706(n) = 2\cdot2^n+ n - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption**. $n$ is a power of $2$.

Do a few substitutions to spot the pattern:
\begin{align*}
a_{n} & =a_{n/2}+n+1\\
 & =a_{n/4}+n+n/2+1+1\\
 & =a_{n/8}+n+n/2+n/4+1+1+1\\
 & =\cdots
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
a_{n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\lg_{2}n}2^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lg_{2}n}1
=2n-1+\lg_{2}n.
$$

Comment: i did'nt get this method.generally we solve recurrence relation problem by conerting into characteristics equation

Comment: You can solve anything any way you want, as long as you get the right answer. The characteristic method is usually reserved for linear homogeneous recurrences (which this is not).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $n=2^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$, to avoid the case of non-integer indices. For $k=0,1,2,3$ we have
\begin{align}
a_1 &= 1\\
a_2 &= 4\\
a_4 &= 9\\
a_8 &= 18
\end{align}
By observation, this follows the pattern $a_n=2n+\lg n-1$. Indeed, if we assume that $a_n=2n+\lg n-1$ for some $n=2^k$, $k\geqslant0$ then we have
\begin{align}
a_{2n} &= a_n + 2n + 1\\
&= 2n + \lg n -1 + 2n + 1\\
&= 2(2n) + \lg 2n -1,
\end{align}
so it follows by induction. (Note that $\lg 2n = \lg 2 + \lg n = 1 + \lg n$.)